# Associate Test case in VS 2017 shows error not connected to a project but I am

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, associate

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Selenium C# for automation testing.  I do see when I right click a Test, 'Associate to Test Case' is enabled.  When I click it though, I do see an error - 'You are not logged into Team Services or Team Foundation Server.  Please login to an account and try again'.   I validated in the Team Explorer - Home, my test repository is displayed.  I did close and reopen Visual Studio and reconnected to my project but still seeing the error.

Any advice would be great.  Thank you.  :)

Answer (score 10):

1. Navigate to the Team Explorer view
2. Click the Home icon
3. Pull down the list to the right of "Home"
4. Select Projects and My Teams / Manage Connections
5. Click Manage Connections / Connect to a Project...
6. Select your repo and click the Connect button

Answer (score 0):

If you still encounter the problem open visual Studio as an administrator.